# Why is there IllegalArgumentException: Bad port: 0?

Tags: java, jetty, illegalargumentexception

I have got this exception. I was trying to make jetty server. According to idea, it must be Handler[] argument, and it is, but this exception. I have no idea for what i need to change. Can anyone help?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server server = new Server();
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
    connector.setPort(8080);
    server.addConnector(connector);
    ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
    resourceHandler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
    resourceHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "index.html" });
    resourceHandler.setResourceBase(".");
    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{new SocketHandler(), resourceHandler}); //#27
    server.setHandler(handlers);
    try {
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
    catch (Throwable t){
        t.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

I get this exception

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad port: 0
>       at java.util.logging.SocketHandler.connect(SocketHandler.java:160)
>       at java.util.logging.SocketHandler.(SocketHandler.java:125)
>       at our.arti.JettyServerArti.JettyStarter.main(JettyStarter.java:27)
>       ... 6 more

If you need more specific details let me know.

Comment: if you read carefully your exception will see: _Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad port: 0_, that means `connector.setPort(8080);` is not working properly... have you debugged, is there a valid `server` and `connector` instances?

Comment: @JordiCastilla when in this program was one Handler instead Handlers it was working with 8080 port

Comment: @JordiCastilla - close, but that's not what it means.  See my answer below; the exception is from the initializer invoked by `new SocketHandler()` which knows nothing of the `ServerConnector` on which the call you mention is made.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger you're probably right I was just guessing after making an edit to the question... anyway since your answer can explain the problem, IMHO does not provide a solution to this issue but a new question... can you expand / explain what OP should do?

Comment: Sorry, guys for my stupidness, but today it starts without any exception, and i haven't change hothing. Maybe port was just close, i don't know. Thank you, everyone

Answer (score 1):

The inner stack trace has a couple details you may have missed.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad port: 0
at java.util.logging.SocketHandler.connect(SocketHandler.java:160)
at java.util.logging.SocketHandler.<init>(SocketHandler.java:125)
```

Note that it is the `SocketHandler.<init>` that is failing, not the `setHandlers()` call; and the error is `Bad port: 0`.  So if you're banging your head on understanding the parameters to `setHandlers()` that's probably barking up the wrong tree...

So what's the `new SocketHandler()` about?  That's what you should be researching...

Comment: The java.util.logging configuration file is where I'd look for the SocketHandler setup.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mark pointed out, the problem is in using SocketHandler. you are using wrong object as parameter. Look at your error, the object of type java.util.logging.SocketHandler is not expected in  your list of handlers. it should be of type org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.
try this instead :
 `handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { resourceHandler, new  DefaultHandler() });`